# python will not print out average

Tags: python, median

I am trying to print out average and median, but I do not understand what I do wrong here, my code will not print out median when my list is even.

```
def print_hi(name):

    sum = 0
    count =0
    average = 0
    list = []
    list2 = []
    while 1:
        enter = float(input('Enter som numbers: '))
        string = str(enter)
        if enter == 0:
            break
        else:
            count += 1
            sum += enter
            average = sum/count
            list.append(string)
    leng = len(list)//2
    left = leng-1
    raghit = leng+1
    if (leng % 2) == 1:
        median = (list[leng])
        print('Median: ', median)
    else:
        median = (left+raghit)/2
        print('Median : ', median)
    print('Average :', round(average, 2))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('PyCharm')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of errors in your code

1. In your else block, while calcualting median, you added the indexes and not the values at those indexes.
2. The right index `raghit` in your code won't be `leng+1`, rather it is `leng`
3. The condition to check in your first if block won't be `leng%2==1`, rather it is `len(list)%2==1`

So the updated code would be

```
sum = 0
count =0
average = 0
list = []
list2 = []
while 1:
    enter = float(input('Enter som numbers: '))
    string = str(enter)
    if enter == 0:
        break
    else:
        count += 1
        sum += enter
        average = sum/count
        list.append(enter)
leng = len(list)//2
left = leng-1
raghit = leng
if (len(list) % 2) == 1:
    median = (list[leng])
    print('Median: ', median)
else:
    median = (list[left]+list[raghit])/2
    print('Median : ', median)
print('Average :', round(average, 2))
```